# Can't get caffe2 running on google colaboratory

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, google-colaboratory, caffe2

after doing `!apt install caffe-cuda` i try to use caffe on google colaboratory but with no result. Any help will be welcomed.
Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt install caffe-cuda` installs cuda for Python3.
For python2 you have to install it manually (cloning the [git folder](https://github.com/bvlc/caffe) and make).
Use the following commands in the colab notebook:

```
#Clone the repo
!cp caffe/Makefile.config.example caffe/Makefile.config

# Make changes to Makefile
!git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
!sed -i 's/# OPENCV_VERSION/OPENCV_VERSION/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/CUDA_ARCH :=/CUDA_ARCH :=\n/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/# USE_CUDNN/USE_CUDNN/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/# WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1/WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1\n/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20/#-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21/#-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/include/\/usr\/local\/include \/usr\/include\/hdf5\/serial/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/lib/\/usr\/local\/lib \/usr\/lib\/x86_64-linux-gnu\/hdf5\/serial/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!sed -i 's/\/usr\/lib\/python2.7\/dist-packages\/numpy/\/usr\/local\/lib\/python2.7\/dist-packages\/numpy/g' caffe/Makefile.config
!cat caffe/Makefile.config

#Install Dependencies
!sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev

#Make
!cd caffe && make -j32
```

Also, I was trying to install pycaffe. So once you make pycaffe, you have to add the `python/` folder of caffe to `sys`. You can achieve it using:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "{path to pycaffe}/python")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,But how can you import caffe.io? I think the above steps may not be complete.hope to get your help,Thanks